# Mejor práctica con componentes anidados en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Supongamos que tengo dos componentes, uno adentro de otro:

```
class Componente1 extends React {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            persona: {
                nombre: "Genaro",
                edad: 125
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SubComponente
                persona={this.state.persona}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Ahora, quiero que se actualice el `SubComponente` cuando el estado de `persona` cambia. Esto se hace automáticamente, pero encontré dos formas para hacerlo:

**Opción 1 (con estado en el subcomponente):**

```
class SubComponente extends React {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            persona: props.persona
        };
    }

    componetWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setState({ persona: props.persona });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Nombre: {this.state.persona.nombre}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

**Opción 2 (con variables de instancia):**

```
class SubComponente extends React {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.persona = props.persona;
    }

    componetWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.persona = props.persona;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Nombre: {this.persona.nombre}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Por complejidad del trabajo (necesito varios métodos para llamar dentro de `SubComponente`) si o sí necesito una clase, **por ende, no puedo realizar lo siguiente**, que sería lo más limpio:

```
function SubComponente(props) {
    return (
        <h1>Nombre: {props.persona.nombre}</h1> 
    );
}
```

Las dudas que me surjen son: Ambas opciones funcionan, pero,

1. ¿Cuál de las dos es mejor? En cuanto performance, mentinibilidad,etc
2. ¿Estoy ejecutando una mala práctica? Es decir, ¿hay una mejor alternativa para manejar estos casos?

Hasta ahora no me crucé con ejemplos que aborden este problema. Me sería de gran ayuda.

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publiqué la misma pregunta en Stack Overflow y obtuve una excelente respuesta: puedo simplemente usar `this.props.persona` sin necesidad de estas sincronizando variables de instancia.

Para más lujo de detalle, ver directamente la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128156/best-practice-with-nested-components-in-react).

Answer (score 0):

Para efectos de performance, es mejor, setear el state con los props

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        persona: props.persona
    };
}
```

Luego pasas props:

```
render() {
    return (
        <SubComponente
            persona={this.state.persona}
        />
    );
}
```

}

Asi no tienes que estar llamando tanto al componente padre. 
Aca puedes encontrar mas info: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Cesar, gracias por responder. Lamentablemente ambas opciones que mencioné son mala práctica. Ahí respondí mi propia pregunta con la respuesta de un usuario de Stack Overflow donde exponen la solución correcta! Saludos y gracias de nuevo!